# optional type () cannot be used as boolean; test for '!=nil' instead

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

**UPDATE**

```
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == ABAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined)
            {
                print("requesting access...")
                addressBook = !ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(emptyDictionary,nil)
                ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook,
                {success, error in
                    if success
                    {
                        self.getContactNames();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("error")
                    }
                })
            }
```

On second line its giving error like below

[image]

How to fix above issue? I'm very new to Swift.

Comment: remove `!` at the after `=`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Shrikanth: Small piece of advice, it is good to always post the code not the screenshot of the code

Comment: updated my question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the method you use is:

```
func ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(_ options: CFDictionary!, _ error: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?>) -> Unmanaged<ABAddressBook>!
```

The return value is an optional Unmanaged object. So you cannot add a `!` before it. Adding `!` before a value can only be used for Bool value.

If you want to force it to have value, add `!` after the method instead.